# Why does this Verilog replicator statement produce a 64 bit long wire?

Tags: verilog, verilator

I'm attempting to capture the carry out of the addition of two N bit numbers with a carry in. My code is:

```
module alu(a, b, f, cOut, z);
   parameter size = 8;          // how many bits is each input                  
   parameter n = size - 1;

   input a;                     // operand a                                    
   input b;                     // operand b
   input f;

   wire [n:0] a;
   wire [n:0] b;
   wire [2:0] f;
   wire [n:0] sum;
   assign {cOut,sum} = {(n+1){a + b + {n{f[2]}}}};
```

In my inner replicator, I'm trying to zero-extend the bit at f[2] to be the size of the operands (f[2] is the carry in). With the outer replicator, I'm trying to zero-extend the addition to fit in n+1 bits. Then cOut will be set to the MSB, which will represent the carry out.

Here's the error that Verilator reports:

```
% verilator -cc alu.v
%Warning-WIDTH: alu.v:22: Operator ASSIGNW expects 9 bits on the Assign RHS, but Assign RHS's REPLICATE generates 64 bits.
%Warning-WIDTH: Use "/* verilator lint_off WIDTH */" and lint_on around source to disable this message.
%Error: Exiting due to 1 warning(s)
%Error: Command Failed /usr/bin/verilator_bin -cc alu.
```

Does anyone know why Verilator thinks that the RHS will be 64 bits? And is there a better way to write this without nested replicators in Verilog?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replicators do not zero extend, they replicate. `{7{f[2]}}` means `{f[2],f[2],f[2],f[2],f[2],f[2],f[2]}`

You misread the message. The RHS is 9 bits but is being assigned 64 bits (the LHS width). `a` and `b` are 8 bit values, and are used as the initial width to be replicated. The Replicator value `(n+8)` is 8. 8*8 is 64, which is now the LHS width value.

To extend leading zeros use `{ {n{1'b0}}, f[2] }`, which in this case will evaluate to `{7'b0000000,f[2]}`

Most synthesizers will generate the proper logic with `assign {cOut,sum} = a + b + f[2];`, and this is assuming you want unsigned logic.

Answer (score 1):

`a` is 8 bits wide

`b` is 8 bits wide

`{n{f2}}` is 8 bits wide

so `a+b+{n{f2}}` is also 8 bits wide

so `{8{a+b+{n{f2}}}}` is 64 bits wide

In cases like this, it often helps to make all the widths explicit: do everything in 9-bits and let the synthesis tool optimize stuff out, something like:

```
sign {cOut,sum} = {1'b0, a} + {1'b0, b} + {{size{1'b0}}, f[2]};
```